# Finite potential well with quantised energy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential-energy

In a finite potential well like that in figure, is the potential constant between $-L/2$ and $L/2$? Since that energy is quantised, if I'm in the second excited state, would the potential still be constant and equal to $0$, so that energy is only kinetic?

[image]

Comment: The potential is by definition constant between $-L/2$ and $L/2$. If you define the potential energy of a state as its expectation value, this will depend also on the potential outside the interval: $U \equiv \int |\phi(x)|^2 V(x) dx$ (here $\phi$ is the wave function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be careful to distinguish between the potential $V(x)$, which determines the dynamics of the system, and the potential energy of the particle. The total energy of a particle in an energy eigenstate (the ground state or any of the excited states) is constant and well-defined. However, because the wavefunction of the particle is spread out through space, the "potential energy" of the particle is not well-defined. In a finite potential well, part of the wavefunction extends into the region where $V>0$. Therefore, you cannot conclude that the potential energy of the particle is zero. There is a non-zero probability of finding the particle in a region where $V(x)\neq0$. Therefore, if you did an experiment to measure the potential energy of the particle, sometimes you would measure zero, and sometimes you would measure $V_0$. You can calculate the expectation value of the potential energy operator (which is well-defined) using the formula
$$\langle V\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^\infty V(x)|\psi(x)|^2.$$
You will find it is greater than zero.

Comment: For example, considering a nuclues with $N$ nucleons. If I want to take a neutron out of the nucleus, I have to give enough energy to it. While giving energy to this neutron, do I increase his potential energy? Or just I give him enough kinetic energy in order it can escape the nuclear force and go from $U=0$ inside the well to $U=0$ but outside the well?(Ignoring the things you said before about wavefunction for make it easier sorry)

Comment: @Salmone You would increase the expectation value of the potential energy (the average potential energy).

Comment: Thank you, but this is not true if I'm still in the potential well right? In that case, even if i'm in an excited state the energy is kinetic energy and maybe some potential energy because of the "spread" of the wavefunction in a region where $V>0$? But in an excited state I can still write $E=\frac{p^2}{2m}$?

Comment: When you add energy to the particle in the well, you will increase its spread into the region where $V>0$, so the average potential energy will increase. Kinetic energy is not well-defined, but the average kinetic energy equals the average momentum squared over $2m$.

Comment: Since the energy is quantised, the average potential energy can increase but the force on the particle is always $0$ becuase $\frac{-\partial U}{\partial x}$?

Comment: Force isn't really a meaningful concept in quantum mechanics. The Schroedinger equation replaces $F=ma$.

Answer (score 2):

The potential is constant by definition. It's independent on your energy state, and it is in fact one of the elements that dictates the behaviour of your system.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on [shape of quantum well](http://web.mit.edu/6.732/www/new_part1b.pdf). Apart from your mentioned rectangular well where $V_0=\text{const}$ between $-a,a$, it can be other forms/shapes of potential wells where potential ground level is some function $V_0=V_0(x)$. Such as,
triangular well :

[image]

or ellipse-like harmonic oscillator quantum well :

[image]

Exact expression of $V_0(x)$ may depend on how you will measure quantum well **width**. Some may it measure at half-maximum voltage level, others at $1 - \frac 1e$ voltage drop level. Anyway, by definition [quantum well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_well) is just a region surrounding minimum potential energy of particle, so it doesn't have to be rectangular (and thus $V_0$ be $\text{const}$) in general. But in your case-finite square well-, yes it is.